# How to make user add images to drawable from system?

Tags: android, image

I'm facing a problem. I'm using an Image GridView of stuff, and I created an object and all. I want to make the user, by tapping a button, to add an image to resources, and then I want to even be able to use that image ID so i can add it to my objects and gridview.

This is my activity: (the part that is needed)

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            textView.setText(mThumbIds.get(position).getDesc());
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds.get(position).getImageID());
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }
        return grid;
    }
}

public void createAll(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    parentGender = prefs.getString("parentGender", "1");
    parentNum = prefs.getString("parentNum", "");
    childName = prefs.getString("childName", "Kiddo");
    final String opening=parentGender+", "+childName;
    if(mThumbIds.size()==0){
        mThumbIds.add(tv);
        mThumbIds.add(cookie);
        mThumbIds.add(toilet);
        mThumbIds.add(toys);
        mThumbIds.add(food);
        mThumbIds.add(water);
    }
    final GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));


    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, final int position, long id) {
```

blah blah blah.....(from now on its the handling of a click on item)

NOTE::: `mThumbIds` is an `ArrayList<E> E>` of my object which contains a title and an image ID!

How do i make a user add an image and use its id??

Comment: At runtime, users cannot add image to `resource`. They can only use image `from` resource.

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung and can i use that resource's id??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned to the comments, you cannot save any image at runtime to resources. You have to deal with an other concept, like storing the image from path of the image at an sqlite database. So, if I were you, first of all I would implement a model class that will describe all the functionality that you want.
So, first step : create a model class :

```
public class MyPicture{
  String filePath, pictureId;
  Bitmap thumbNail, pictureBmp;
} /// constructor , setters, getters etc
```

Then , I would implement a method to pick pictures the user from the sd card OR from MediaStore in other words.

```
// first open an activity to browse the pictures from MediaStore and return the result with code CODE.
public void browsePictures(){
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, CODE);
}
```

You can see more information for startActivityForResult method [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)
Then receive the results

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) { // we have bitmap from filesystem!
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

        InputStream inputStream = null;

        if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT.equals(selectedImage.getScheme())) {
            try {
                inputStream = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE.equals(selectedImage.getScheme())) {
                try {
                    inputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedImage.getPath());
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        // here you have to store the data that you received. In other words , 
       // create the MyPicture object and then store it to your sqlite db.
    }

}
```

For further information for onActivityResult method take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)).
As you can read in the documentation page , the startActivityForResult and the onActivityResult are a pair of methods that must be used together. The variable 'CODE' is the variable that help us to differentiate multiple results that we receive in onActivityResult method.

There is many tutorials for instructions to set an sqlite database.
You can take a look  at the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

Comment: thank you! but i didnt understand the browsePicture method.. is it an onClick method of my button? and what does the symbol CODE represent?
@karvoynistas

Comment: I edited my answer. Please take a look. Also, about the onClickMethod , the answer is yes, if you want to browse the pictures after the click.

Comment: my app crashes when i click this button. do i need any permission?

Comment: yes, you have to add the android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE